# Finding link to ArcFM Object Reader download?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcfm

Does anyone know where i can find a link to the Arcfm Object Reader 10.2.1c (64-bit) for download which works with ArcFM solution 10.2.1c and ArcGIS for server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object readers are available on [Schneider's support website](https://infrastructurecommunity.schneider-electric.com/community/support/gis/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~category[object-readers]~objecttype~objecttype[document]), including [10.2.1c](https://infrastructurecommunity.schneider-electric.com/docs/DOC-7972).

You will need to:

> Log in to follow, share, and participate in this community